# How do I rotate the camera/viewPlatform in java 3d

Tags: java, view, camera, angle, java-3d

I just started java3D and I can move the camera up/down/left/right/forwards/backwards, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the camera angle change, for example, change from looking forward to looking left. Could someone give me an example? Also, should I be putting            getViewingPlatform().getViewPlatformTransform().setTransform(test.position); in my main method, or should I do something else?

I've tried just using the mouse and rotating the view
    OrbitBehavior orbit = new OrbitBehavior(canvas,      OrbitBehavior.REVERSE_ROTATE);

```
orbit.setSchedulingBounds(new BoundingSphere());
orbit.setRotXFactor(2);
orbit.setRotYFactor(2);
```

But it doesnt work when I add   getViewingPlatform().getViewPlatformTransform().setTransform(test.position);
to the while loop in the main method. The viewing angle repeatedly gets reset.

Comment: Please include what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of steering the viewer (camera) using angles, you can steer it by defining a 3D "gazePoint" (the point attention is focussed on).  To keep the camera from tilting sideways, define upDir = [ 0 , 1, 0 ] (J3D assumes +y-axis is up).

Then, modify the viewingTransform that lives in simpleUniverse.

Here is example code from my app:

```
// ***********declare these variables in class where canvas3D lives *****
//J3D stuff
public InteractiveCanvas3D  canvas3D;
public SimpleUniverse       simpleUniv;
private Transform3D         viewingTransform;
private TransformGroup viewingTransformGroup;

public  static Point3d viewersLocation;
public  static Point3d gazePoint;  //point viewer is looking at

// and initialize as follows:

viewingTransformGroup = simpleUniv.getViewingPlatform().getViewPlatformTransform();
viewingTransform = new Transform3D();


//called to update viewer's location and gaze:
// *********************** UpdateViewerGeometryJ3D 
public void UpdateViewerGeometryJ3D()  {
    Point3d eye = viewersLocation;  
    Point3d center = gazePoint;
    Vector3d up = upDir;
    viewingTransform.lookAt(eye, center, up);
    viewingTransform.invert();
    viewingTransformGroup.setTransform(viewingTransform);
```

I forget why the viewing transform has to be inverted.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a question. When you move up down left right and the camera angle changes, do the directions stay the same? For example, if I were to move forward, then look right, but then hold the forward key again, would I move forward in the new direction(right), or forward in the old direction(start direction)?

Comment: No.  The gazePoint ("lookAt()") does not effect the movement of the viewer, only the direction looked.

To make an analogy to rubbernecking drivers, let's say there is a car fire on the shoulder of the highway.   The drivers keep their gaze fixed on the location of the burning car (GazePoint).   His neck keeps turning to keep looking at the same fixed point as he is passing by it.  

I have found that the "moving viewer + fixed gaze point" technique gives the user a realistic sense of being in a 3D space.   It is more intuitive, since it mimics the way humans fix their attention on an object.